# Extension of odd/even town problem.

Tags: combinatorics

The original odd/even town problem:
Let $R_1,\dots,R_m$ be subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. $|R_i|$ is odd for every $i$ and $|R_i \cap R_j|$ is even for every $i\not = j$. Then $m\le n$.

Easy extension:
Let $R_1,\dots,R_m$ be subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $p$ a prime number. $|R_i| \not \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) for every $i$ and $|R_i \cap R_j| \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) for every $i\not = j$. Then $m\le n$.

My problem:
Suppose $R_1,\dots,R_m$ are subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ satisfying $|R_i| \not\equiv 0 $ (mod $6$) for every $i$ and $|R_i\cap R_j| \equiv 0$ (mod $6$) for every $i\not = j$. Prove that $m \le 2n$.

I don't know how to deduce the above inequality $m \le 2n$ from the easy extension of odd/even town problem.

Comment: What is another way to say that an integer $a\not \equiv 0\pmod6$?

Comment: @sigma-finite I guess $a \equiv 1,2,3,4,5 \pmod 6$?

Comment: True, but it may be more useful to think about it modulo $2$ and $3$ to apply your knowledge of prime-town.

Comment: @sigma-finite if $a \not \equiv 0 \qmod 6$, then $a \equiv 0,1 \qmod 2$ and $a \equiv 0,1,2 \qmod 3$ right? That doesn’t provide any additional information.

Comment: If $6$ doesn't divide $n$ but $n$ is even, what do you know about $n$, modulo $3$?

Comment: @sigma-finite So we can split the subsets into odd-size and even-size and problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know, is this result tight? Does there exist $2n$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose sizes are nonzero $\pmod 6$, but whose intersection's sizes are multiples of $6$, for some integer $n$?